# Firebase function shows error on opening firebase function URL

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

So I've a scenario where when I open the firebase function's url - https://us-central1-geochatterthing.cloudfunctions.net/getWall

I get the below error:

> {"error":{"status":"INVALID_ARGUMENT","message":"Bad Request"}}

Also, my getWall functions in Cloud Functions look like the below image.

[image]

And below is the link to the api-http.js file:

https://gist.github.com/shubham6996/53cea6696b6d565b7f1ffce53bdaabf4

**UPDATED QUESTION:**

This function gets called from my React Native Application using the below code:

```
const wallFunc = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('getWall');

let result = await wallFunc({size: 15});
```

And when I check the output of `result` using below code:

```
console.log("Show result = "+JSON.stringify(result, this.getCircularReplacer()));

 getCircularReplacer = () => {
        const seen = new WeakSet();
        return (key, value) => {
          if (typeof value === "object" && value !== null) {
            if (seen.has(value)) {
              return;
            }
            seen.add(value);
          }
          return value;
        };
    };
```

And the above code shows me below output in the console:

> Show Result =
>   {"data":{"docs":[{"sort":[1530702073924],"id":"04dhcfzDZbNLZoekfhl3"}],"hits":1}}

Here "id": `04dhcfzDZbNLZoekfhl3` is the id of a document fetched from the Firebase database collection. But I want to be able to fetch data of every document from that collection instead of just one document.

Also, in the beginning the error I mentioned of "status":"INVALID_ARGUMENT" , I have found something to this error:

> If the client trigger is invoked, but the request is in the wrong
>   format, such as not being JSON, having invalid fields, or missing the
>   data field, the request is rejected with 400 Bad Request, with an
>   error code of INVALID_ARGUMENT.

source: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable-reference

And in my application, when I call the callable function using

```
const wallFunc = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('getWall');

let result = await wallFunc({size: 15});
```

I do pass size as a parameter here but I don't know if I'm missing something or not here.

And in the [api-http.js](https://gist.github.com/shubham6996/53cea6696b6d565b7f1ffce53bdaabf4) file, in this file at line 36 it shows that data has 2 objects size and from whereas I'm only passing size parameter.

P.S. - I might be wrong in explaining my problem here because I'm actually redesigning this Application. So I'm confused about the right approach here.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently you are mixing up [Callable Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) and [HTTP Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events).

When you call a Cloud Function directly via an URL (https://us-central1-geochatterthing.cloudfunctions.net/getWall) it means this Cloud Function is an HTTP one.

But it seems from the Cloud Function code (`_firebase.functions.https.onCall()`) that it is a Callable one.

Therefore you should call it the way it gets called from your React Native application (cf. the code in your question) and not through an URL. See also this specific section of the documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#call_the_function

Comment: Hey, I did go through everything you recommend me but couldn't figure out anything so far. Can you please check my updated question? I have a little different approach to the question and and an extra information.

Comment: What I dion't understand is why you want to calla a Callable function through an URL and not the way it is explained in the documentation. Do you have some specific constraints?

Comment: As explained in the doc you refer to: "If you **are** able to use the Android, iOS, or web SDKs, **you're recommended to do that** instead of directly implementing this protocol. The SDKs provide features to save coding effort, as detailed in Call Functions from Your App (https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable).". Apparently your Callable Cloud Function fetches only one document. You can either modify it to call several documents (this is to be done **in the Cloud Function code itself**) OR you call it several time from your front-end (may not be the most efficient way...)